# access vba add a linked table/table link without setting a primary key

Tags: ms-access, vba, primary-key, linked-tables

I wrote a statement below in Access VBA to add a linked table/table link from a SQL server.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC", "ODBC;driver=SQL server;server=Server_Name;database=Database_Name", _
acTable, "table_name", "table_name", False
```

Access always ask me to set a unnique record identifier. 
[Access message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EewI.png)

As I will have to loop this command, in SQL server I have already created indices for those tables and I don't want to set a primary key, is there a way of suppressing this message box or giving a 'cancel' with a statement?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - why don't you want to set a PK?

Comment: ^^ This. A table without a PK isn't really a table, just something that looks like it. And a linked table without PK will always be read-only in Access.

Comment: Add a field named `id` as PK (with autoincrement), This should be recognized automatic. In Access-Option you can define the names of the autorecognized fields.

Comment: Hi, I have created indices in SQL server for those tables so that each row is unique. I dont want a key because I dont want the machine to sort the table every time when a new record needs to be inserted.

Comment: [Link tables vba](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s285/linkviewsvba.htm).